# How does save work in mongoID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, mongoid

There is a Object and embedded SubObject

```
class Object
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :sub_objects
end

class SubObject
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :str1,:type => String
  field :ind1,:type => Integer

  embedded_in :object
end
```

Console output

```
irb(main):060:0> obj = Object.first
=> #<Object _id: 4fd5ed971d41c8252c001f49, ..............>
irb(main):061:0> obj.sub_objects.size
=> 24000
irb(main):062:0> obj.save
=> true
```

Here is interesting thing happens.
Mongoid does not actually save the object because the object was not changed.
I.e. there is no call to mongodb.
But the save operation itself takes 18 (!!!) seconds.

Can anyone explain me what is happening and how can I avoid it?

Thanks.

Comment: Update: I figured out there is validation issues. Seems that it goes recursively through all run_validate! methods of all children and that causes for time wasting. But why it does not check that the object was  not <u>changed?</u>

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
obj.save if !obj.persisted? || obj.changed?  # only save if new record, or something changed
```